# Change css on moblie / desktop version in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website that is split up in main content and some extra content. The extra content should be displayed on the right side of the website, when using a large screen and beneath the main content when displayed on a small screen.

[image: Website layout on desktop and mobile devices]

There fore I have the following structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">main content</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">extra content</div>
</div>
```

That is all working fine, but now I want to separate the columns with a simple line. So what i did was adding `border-right: 1px solid #ddd` to the main content column. That looks good on desktop devices, but how do i get it, so that on mobile devices that border disappears and instead `border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd` is added?

I could use JS to detect the screen size and then aplly the correct CSS, but that is kind of a cheaty way and i want the website to work with JS disabled, too.

Maybe there is another way to separate the columns then using borders?

Comment: You don't even need `col-xs-12`. If xs, or sm for that matter, is not declared, it will default to 12 (anything under md will be 12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Media-queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) as bootstrap uses them for layout like

## html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 main">main content</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">extra content</div>
</div>
```

## css

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
.main 
{
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
.main 
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose 768px?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own media query. 
Here's an example you can use with a custom css file (Using the mobile-first approach)

```
// Assume mobile devices first:
.col-md-10 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd
}

/* When the screen get to at least "sm" breakpoint change the borders
   Small devices (tablets, 768px and up)
*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-10 {
         border-bottom: 0;
         border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
}
```